# How can I subdivide a lattice?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When using a lattice for a lattice deform modifier, I often want to use a more detailed lattice. However, I can not edit it in the viewport in edit mode, I can only move already existing vertices. How can I subdivide a lattice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A lattice is not an actual mesh, and is in reality more akin to an array of hook empties. So, just like an empty, you can't edit in edit mode. However, there is a way to subdivide it. Go to *Properties > Data* and you can change the resolution for the height, width, and depth. Note that these are relative, so rotating will quite possibly make the top on the bottom, or the right on the left.

[image: Lattice Sub Div Example]